# Pointfree conversion

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I have some traverse/accessor functions to work with my mesh type:

```
cell :: Mesh a -> Int -> Maybe (Cell a)
neighbour :: Mesh a -> Int -> Cell a -> Maybe (Cell a)
owner :: Mesh a -> Cell a -> Maybe (Cell a)
```

To avoid passing mesh to each function and to handle fails I've created monadic version of them via this compound monad:

```
type MMesh a b = MaybeT (State (Mesh a)) b
```

So, I have such monadic accessors:

```
getMesh = get :: MMesh a (Mesh a) -- just to remove type declarations

cellM id = getMesh >>= (MaybeT . return) <$> (\m -> cell m id)
neighbourM idx cell = getMesh >>= (MaybeT . return) <$> (\m -> neighbour m idx cell)
ownerM cell = getMesh >>= (MaybeT . return) <$> (\m -> owner m cell)
```

They obviously follow the same pattern and I would be glad to move common part to some external function, say `liftMesh` to rewrite the code above as:

```
cellM = liftMesh cell
neighbourM = liftMesh neighbour
ownerM - liftMesh owner
```

But this first needs the functions to be rewritten in pointfree style to omit variable number of arguments. And that's where I'm stuck, so could anyone help to convert this to pointfree or find other ways achive the same result?

Upd: adding the full text here: http://pastebin.com/nmJVNx93

Comment: Please make your code self-contained. In particular, add your import statements and definitions for `Mesh`, `Cell`, etc. It will be easier for people to make sure that their point-free versions typecheck.

Comment: Have you tried the pointfree tool?

Comment: Thank you for an idea but it seems that it's too difficult for pointfree tool or I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`gets`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:gets), which returns a projection of the state specified by an arbitrary function on it, and `MaybeT`:

```
cellM ix = MaybeT (gets (\m -> cell m ix))

neighbourM ix c = MaybeT (gets (\m -> neighbour m ix c))

owner c = MaybeT (gets (\m -> owner m c))
```

(N.B.: I recommend not naming things `id`. The standard `id` function is too important, which makes the name clash very confusing.)

To make that more pointfree, reorder the arguments of your functions as appropriate. For instance:

```
cell :: Int -> Mesh a -> Maybe (Cell a)

cellM ix = MaybeT (gets (cell ix))
```

(You could go all the way and write `cellM = MaybeT . gets . cell` instead, but I feel that would excessively obscure what `cellM` does.)

P.S.: Given that you are using `State`, odds are you are also interested in functions that modify a mesh. If you aren't, however, `Reader` would be more appropriate than `State`.

Comment: Reordering the arguments may not be an option, though.

Comment: @Jubobs If it isn't, then don't :) (Or use `flip`, but I really don't feel like adding that to the answer. It gets ugly...)

Comment: Yes, it gets ugly quickly. I was just nitpicking.

Comment: Suddenly, `cell` and others returns `Maybe (Cell a)`, which is handled by `MaybeT` transformer, so applying gets results in `join $ (MaybeT . return) <$> gets (\m -> cell m id)` which is not much better

Comment: @AlexanderYushkov You only need `MaybeT (gets (\m -> cell m ix))`.  The type of `MaybeT` is `m (Maybe a) -> MaybeT m a`, so it can do the conversion you want on its own.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that realy works as intended. So the problem was really not in pointfree conversion but in proper usage of libraries